# c++ design: avoid iterating over types with an existing class hierarchy

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Please consider the following (simplified) class hierarchy and processing functions:

```
struct msgBase
{
    virtual int msgType() const=0;
};

struct msgType1:public msgBase
{
    virtual int msgType() const{return 1;}
};

struct msgType2:public msgBase
{
    virtual int msgType() const {return 2;}
};

void process(const msgType1& mt1)
{
    // processing for message type 1
}

void process(const msgType2& mt2)
{
    // processing for message type 2
}

void process(const msgBase& mbase)
{
    switch(mbase.msgType())
    {
    case 1:
        process(static_cast<const msgType1&>(mbase));
        break;
    case 2:
        process(static_cast<const msgType2&>(mbase));
        break;
    }
}
```

In an integrated design, msgBase would be given a virtual "process" method, to avoid needing to iterate over the types.

If it's not possible or desirable to modify any of the classes, are there any alternatives to iterating over the types?

I've experimented with a decorator/factory pattern where a parallel hierarchy of classes encapsulates the given classes, and implements the necessary virtual functions, but this results in an awful lot of boilerplate, and the factory function *still needs to iterate over the types*!

I could replace the switch statement with a series of dyamic_casts, but that still leaves the same weaknesses.

Comment: I believe the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) is what you're looking for. It allows the base class to call the subclass's process method.

Comment: Maybe create a table of function pointers indexed by msgType?  In this case, the process() functions would all accept `const msgBase&`, and the downcast would happen inside the process() functions.

Comment: @rangu: can you elaborate on who that would work in this case? I can't change the msgType hierarchy, so I'd have to wrap it in a CRTP class, and I'm passed a base pointer, so I can't see how the CRTP template would know what class to work on.

Comment: @Peter: yes, there are a few ways of encapsulating the nastiness. I was hoping someone would come up with a way of refactoring it out altogether.

Comment: @SimonElliott I'm very curious. In the code above, you pass msg objects by reference. Which means at client side, you will give the derived msgs. Why the first 2 overloaded process function doesn't fit your need.

Answer (score 2):

As requested by Simon, here is what I mean by CRTP:

```
typedef <class Derived>
struct msgBase
{
    virtual void process(){
        // redirect the call to the derived class's process()
        static_cast<Derived*>(this) -> process();
};

struct msgType1:public msgBase<msgType1>
{
    void process(){
        // process as per type-1
    }
};

struct msgType2:public msgBase<msgType1>
{
    void process(){
        // process as per type-2
    }
};
```

What's happening here? Consider this case:

```
msgBase* msg = new msgType1();
msg->process();
```

normally (without CRTP) this would only call `msgBase::process()`. But now, `msgBase` "knows" about `msgType1` using the template, so it is redirected to `msgType1::process` *at compile time*.

Comment: Afterthought: I missed the fact that you don't want to modify the classes. This is a big modification, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the expansion, but as you say I'm unable to modify the classes.

Comment: You're missing one layer in your class hierarchy. It should be `msgBase`, then the missing template class `msgBaseImpl` or something, and then `msgType1`.

Comment: msgBase::process shouldn't be virtual. The base class should call something such as "process_impl", which the derived classes should implement.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work:

These classes are used to do the casting automatically:

```
struct dispatcher_base {
    virtual void process(const msgBase&) = 0;
};

template <class T>
struct dispatcher_impl : dispatcher_base {
    void process(const msgBase& b) override {
        ::process(static_cast<const T&>(b));
    }
};
```

We'll store them in a `map`:

```
auto g_table = std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<dispatcher_base>>{};
```

But now you have to initialize this table somewhere:

```
template <class T>
void register_msg() {
    g_table[T{}.msgType()].reset(new dispatcher_impl<T>{});
}
...
register_msg<msgType1>();
register_msg<msgType2>();
```

You can add an `assert` to `register_msg` to make sure that `msgType`s are unique.

Your `process` function will look like this:

```
void process(const msgBase& b) {
    assert(g_table.find(b.msgType()) != g_table.end());
    g_table[b.msgType()]->process(b);
}
```

You can replace `assert` with any other logic of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify the classes then you can use decorators to get polymorphic type deduction.

```
struct DecorBase {
    DecorBase(msgBase& b) : b_(b) {}
    virtual ~DecorBase() {}
    virtual void process() = 0;
    msgBase& b_;
};

struct DecorType1 : public DecorBase {
    DecorType1(msgType1& t1) : DecorBase(t1) {}
    void process() override {
        std::cout << "Processing Type 1" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct DecorType2 : public DecorBase {
    DecorType2(msgType2& t2) : DecorBase(t2) {}
    void process() override {
        std::cout << "Processing Type 2" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And use it like this:

```
msgType1 t1;
msgType2 t2;
DecorType1 dt1(t1); // Wrap objects in respective decorator.
DecorType2 dt2(t2);

DecorBase& base = dt2;
base.process();     // Uses polymorphism to call function in derived type.
```

This will require you to write a decorator for every derived type but at least you don't have to iterate over all types during the function call.

Comment: I looked at this approach, but given that I'm supplied with a pointer or reference to msgBase only, I needed a factory to instantiate my decorated types. This factory had to iterate over the types so as to determine which decorated type to instantiate. It's a nice object design, and it encapusales the untidiness cleanly, but it's a lot of extra boilerplate code.